How to use images uploaded from a HTML web-page using Python Flask
I am trying to create an image recogniton program and so far I have made the model and all of the actual AI aspect of things. However, when it came to implementing this into a website, I have been having lots of unexpected troubles when I'm trying to display a prediction on another web-page using Python Flask.
For instance, whenever I click on upload after choosing my image, it just opens a new web-page with the directory of the image and project files where I can navigate the files/folders. It should just be a container with the prediction and some text.
I am quite new to this style of programming so I'm not sure how to solve the bugs as of now, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have linked a photo of the current project directory structure.

Here is my Python Flask code
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('html/enter_p.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file:
        # Save the file
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
        file.save(file_path)
        # Redirect to the prediction page
        return redirect(url_for('predict', filename=file.filename))

@app.route('/predict/<filename>')
def predict(filename):
    # Load your model and make a prediction
    result = model.predict(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))  # Replace with your prediction logic
    return render_template('results.html', prediction=result, filename=filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Here is my results html code:
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Prediction Result: {{ prediction }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename) }}" alt="Uploaded Mole Image" width="300px">
        <br>

And if necessary, here is my upload form:
            <form action = "../static/uploads/" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                <input type = "file" name = "file" accept = "image/*" required>
                <button type = "submit">Upload</button>
            </form>


Why did you set your form's action attribute to ../static/uploads and not the path to your route {{ url_for('.uploads') }}?

Won't ../static/uploads put the image the user uploads into the uploads folder?

The action attribute defines where your form should be sent. In your case, this corresponds to your endpoint upload_file, which then saves the sent file to the folder. Sorry, my path is wrong too. It should be action="{{ url_for('upload_file') }}".

I have replaced ../static/uploads with what you mentioned, but whenever I click upload, it opens a webpage saying ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I'm also confused about what upload_file is since I have no variables or files with this name.

upload_file is the identifier/name of the function with the route /upload in your example code. In this you query the value of the form field for the file that was uploaded and save the file, if available, in the folder uploads.

I posted another answer if you mind looking at that, please.

I have changed your code slightly and combined the two routes index and upload_file into one. Since the form is now sent to the same address from which the form is retrieved, it is no longer necessary to set the action attribute of the form.
Another advantage is that the lines redirect(request.url) send a GET request to the address used, which is not possible with your POST variant because it does not accept GET.
./app.py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)
import os

# ...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'uploads')
)
os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            # Save the file
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            # Redirect to the prediction page
            return redirect(url_for('predict', filename=file.filename))
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict/<path:filename>')
def predict(filename):
    result = model.predict(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) 
    return render_template('results.html', prediction=result, filename=filename)

# ...

./templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" required>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

./templates/results.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Predict</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Prediction Result: {{ prediction }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename) }}" alt="Uploaded Mole Image" width="300px">
        <br>
        <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Upload another image</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


The error is mostly fixed now. Only issue is that after uploading, nothing happens. I notice that the text next to the choose file box goes from the name of the file to "No file chosen." Also nothing has been saved under the uploads folder.

@CelCoding Normally you should be redirected to the results page. If this is not the case, either the attribute name of the input field does not match the requested key for the dictionary request.files or the file name is empty, meaning no file is selected. It is possible that a typo on my part caused the error. There was a comma in the form tag. But that should not be a problem.

@CelCoding Can you add a print(request.files) command after the line if request.method == 'POST': and print the dictionary? The result should tell us what is failing.
